# Issue with Resizing Shapes by Dragging Handles in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, resize

I'm working on a JavaScript application where I'm implementing functionality to resize shapes by dragging their handles. I've encountered an issue with the resizing functionality. Also, when resizing shapes from the top or left handles The position of Shape changed.

```js
const DrawJs = {
    selectedShape: null,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    container: null,
    resizing: false,

    init: function (containerId) {
        const container = document.querySelector(containerId);
        this.container = container;
        return container;
    },

    drawRectangle: function (width, height, x, y, color) {
        const shape = document.createElement("div");
        shape.classList.add("resizable-shape");
        shape.style.width = width + "px";
        shape.style.height = height + "px";
        shape.style.left = x + "px";
        shape.style.top = y + "px";
        shape.style.backgroundColor = color;
        this.createHandle("handle-top", shape);
        this.createHandle("handle-bottom", shape);
        this.createHandle("handle-left", shape);
        this.createHandle("handle-right", shape);
        // Add event listeners for drag and drop
        this.draggable(shape);

        this.container.appendChild(shape);
    },
    createHandle: function (handleClass, shape) {
        const handle = document.createElement("div");
        handle.classList.add("resizable-handle", handleClass);

        let isResizing = false;
        let startX, startY, startWidth, startHeight;

        const startResize = (e) => {
            isResizing = true;
            startX = e.clientX;
            startY = e.clientY;
            startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(shape).width);
            startHeight = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(shape).height);
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
        };

        const resize = (e) => {
            if (isResizing) {
                if (handleClass.includes("right")) {
                    shape.style.width = startWidth + e.clientX - startX + "px";
                } else if (handleClass.includes("bottom")) {
                    shape.style.height = startHeight + e.clientY - startY + "px";
                } else if (handleClass.includes("left")) {
                    const newWidth = startWidth + startX - e.clientX;
                    shape.style.width = newWidth + "px";
                    shape.style.left = startX - newWidth + "px";
                } else if (handleClass.includes("top")) {
                    const newHeight = startHeight + startY - e.clientY;
                    shape.style.height = newHeight + "px";
                    shape.style.top = startY - newHeight + "px";
                }
            }
        };

        const stopResize = () => {
            isResizing = false;
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize);
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
        };

        handle.addEventListener("mousedown", startResize);
        shape.appendChild(handle);
    },
    draggable: function (element) {
        let isDragging = false;
        let offsetX, offsetY;

        element.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
            if (!this.resizing) {
                isDragging = true;
                const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
                offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left;
                offsetY = e.clientY - rect.top;
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
            if (isDragging) {
                const newX = e.clientX - offsetX;
                const newY = e.clientY - offsetY;
                element.style.left = newX + "px";
                element.style.top = newY + "px";
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
            isDragging = false;
        });
    }
};

const container = DrawJs.init("#container");

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    DrawJs.drawRectangle(100, 60, 0, 0, "blue");
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
}


#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.resizable-shape {
    position: absolute;
}

.resizable-handle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: none;
}
.resizable-shape:hover .resizable-handle {
    display: block;
}
.handle-top {
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: ns-resize;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.handle-bottom {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: ns-resize;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.handle-left {
    top: 50%;
    left: -5px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: ew-resize;
}

.handle-right {
    top: 50%;
    right: -5px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Expectation:** I'm seeking guidance on how to properly adjust the position of the shape when resizing from handles to ensure it maintains its position relative to the handle being dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed issues when dragging and resizing simultaneously. But the real issue was in calculating how much to move left/top. So instead of `shape.style.left = startX - newWidth + "px"` you should `shape.style.left = startX - (newWidth - startWidth) + "px"`. That is: offset by the diff between the new width and the old one.

```js
const DrawJs = {
  selectedShape: null,
  offsetX: 0,
  offsetY: 0,
  container: null,
  resizing: false,
  dragging: false,

  init: function(containerId) {
    const container = document.querySelector(containerId);
    this.container = container;
    return container;
  },

  drawRectangle: function(width, height, x, y, color) {
    const shape = document.createElement("div");
    shape.classList.add("resizable-shape");
    shape.style.width = width + "px";
    shape.style.height = height + "px";
    shape.style.left = x + "px";
    shape.style.top = y + "px";
    shape.style.backgroundColor = color;
    this.createHandle("handle-top", shape);
    this.createHandle("handle-bottom", shape);
    this.createHandle("handle-left", shape);
    this.createHandle("handle-right", shape);
    // Add event listeners for drag and drop
    this.draggable(shape);

    this.container.appendChild(shape);
  },

  createHandle: function(handleClass, shape) {
    const handle = document.createElement("div");
    handle.classList.add("resizable-handle", handleClass);


    let startX, startY, startWidth, startHeight;

    const startResize = (e) => {
      this.resizing = true;

      startX = e.clientX;
      startY = e.clientY;
      startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(shape).width);
      startHeight = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(shape).height);
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
    };

    const resize = (e) => {
      if (this.resizing) {
        if (handleClass.includes("right")) {
          shape.style.width = startWidth + e.clientX - startX + "px";
        } else if (handleClass.includes("bottom")) {
          shape.style.height = startHeight + e.clientY - startY + "px";
        } else if (handleClass.includes("left")) {
          const newWidth = startWidth + startX - e.clientX;
          shape.style.width = newWidth + "px";
          shape.style.left = startX - (newWidth - startWidth) + "px";
        } else if (handleClass.includes("top")) {
          const newHeight = startHeight + startY - e.clientY;
          shape.style.height = newHeight + "px";
          shape.style.top = startY - (newHeight - startHeight) + "px";
        }
      }
    };

    const stopResize = () => {
      this.resizing = false;
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopResize);
    };

    handle.addEventListener("mousedown", startResize);
    shape.appendChild(handle);
  },

  draggable: function(element) {
    let isDragging = false;
    let offsetX, offsetY;

    element.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
      if (!this.resizing) {
        this.dragging = true
        const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left;
        offsetY = e.clientY - rect.top;
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      if (this.dragging) {
        const newX = e.clientX - offsetX;
        const newY = e.clientY - offsetY;
        element.style.left = newX + "px";
        element.style.top = newY + "px";
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      this.dragging = false
    });
  }
};

const container = DrawJs.init("#container");

addEventListener("load", () => {
  DrawJs.drawRectangle(120, 80, 10, 10, "blue");
});
```

```css
.resizable-shape {
  position: absolute;
}

.resizable-handle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: none;
}

.resizable-shape:hover .resizable-handle {
  display: block;
}

.handle-top {
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: ns-resize;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.handle-bottom {
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: ns-resize;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.handle-left {
  top: 50%;
  left: -5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

.handle-right {
  top: 50%;
  right: -5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```